# combining dataframe plots in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-visualization

Something I really like about R is that the `plot()` command lets you quickly see a lot of what is going on in a data frame

e.g.

```
library(datasets)
iris_df<-data.frame(iris)
plot(iris_df)
```

gives you this:
[image]

Whilst this set of graphs is nice it doesn't deal well with categorical variables. Column 5 of our data is species, and whilst the last row of the graphs tells us how species relates to the other variables it would be nice to see how the clustering in the other graphs relates to species.

You can do this via

```
plot(iris_df[is.element(iris_df$Species, "versicolor"),])
plot(iris_df[is.element(iris_df$Species, "setosa"),])
plot(iris_df[is.element(iris_df$Species, "virginica"),])
```

but this gives you three separate plots. I'd like to combine them and visualise them with different colours so you can see how the clustering works in one image.

(I imagine this might be equivalent to using `hold on` in matlab )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `col` argument to change color and/or `pch` to change shape:

```
plot(iris, col = iris$Species, pch = 15 + as.numeric(iris$Species))
```

[image]

Comment: +1, however, 10% of men are red/green colorblind, & you have a lot of overlapping circles.  This plot can be improved by using solid circles (`pch=16`), using black, red & blue, and using partial transparency (`col = with(iris, ifelse(Species==1, rgb(0,0,0,alpha=.5), ifelse(Species==2, rgb(1,0,0,alpha=.5), rgb(0,0,1,alpha=.5))`).

Comment: @gung  , thanks for the comment. `plot(iris, col = iris$Species, pch = c(16, 17, 18)[as.numeric(iris$Species)] )` would also help